# Add object key for each serialized element in django-rest-framework

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework to return Orders. Orders are rendered using the default JSONRenderer class. Right now, they are returned in this form:

```
{
    "count": 50,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sales/?_=1444830088899&page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "order_number": 20,
            "customer_number": 100
        },
        {
            "order_number": 21,
            "customer_number": 101
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like it django-rest-framework to render it like this instead:

```
{
    "count": 50,
    "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sales/?_=1444830088899&page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": {
        "20": {
            "customer_number": 100
        },
        "21": {
            "customer_number": 101
        }
    }
}
```

The view:

```
class SalesList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SalesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return get_sales(self.request, None)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default pagination style used by `PageNumberPagination` pagination class. To change this pagination style and return our custom response in `results` key, we need to [**implement a custom pagination style**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#custom-pagination-styles) which will extend from `PageNumberPagination`.

In the `CustomPagination` class, we will override the `get_paginated_response()` and specify our custom pagination output style.

```
from rest_framework.compat import OrderedDict   

class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        # prepare the custom results using 'data'
        custom_results = {x['order_number']:{'customer_number': x['customer_number']} for x in data}     

        return Response(OrderedDict([
            ('count', self.page.paginator.count),
            ('next', self.get_next_link()),
            ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
            ('results', custom_results) # specify the custom results dictionary
        ]))
```

Then we need to specify this custom pagination class in our DRF settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'my_project.my_app.pagination.CustomPagination', # specify the custom pagination class
...       
}
```